# lock wait timeout exceeded try restarting transaction

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, innodb

I must say that I am fairly new to backend development and mysql programming as well. I just started learning how to develop backend using Node.js. To operate with mysql I am using Sequelize. When I call an api listed below I get an error - **lock wait timeout exceeded try restarting transaction** and the code jump into catch block. I believe that this should be an error caused with the wrong use of sequelize transaction which will finally invoke innodb transaction. But I can't figure out this problem and I would need you kind help.

Thank you in advance

```
const registerUsers = async (req, res) => {
    const {
        body
    } = req;

    try {
        await db.sequelize.transaction(async (t) => {
            await body.users.reduce(async (promise, item) => {
                await promise;
                const user = await db.KSUser.findOne({
                    where: {
                        phoneNum: item.userId,
                    },
                    transaction: t
                });

                if (!user) {
                    const newUser = await db.KSUser.create({
                        phoneNum: item.userId,
                        verifyURL: item.password,
                        loginType: body.type,
                    }, {
                        include: [{
                                model: db.KSUserCredential,
                                as: 'credential',
                            },
                            {
                                model: db.KSUserStatus,
                                as: 'userStatus',
                            },
                            {
                                model: db.KSTrainInfo,
                                as: 'trainInfo',
                            },
                            {
                                model: db.KSFollowInfo,
                                as: 'followInfo',
                            },
                            {
                                model: db.KSLikeInfo,
                                as: 'likeInfo',
                            },
                        ],
                        transaction: t
                    });

                    await newUser.createCredential({
                        countryCode: body.countryCode,
                    }, {
                        transaction: t
                    });
                    await newUser.createUserStatus({ transaction: t });
                    await newUser.createTrainInfo({ transaction: t });
                    await newUser.createFollowInfo({ transaction: t });
                    await newUser.createLikeInfo({ transaction: t });
                }
            }, Promise.resolve());

            return apiResponse.successResponse(
                res,
                'Successfully registered accounts'
            );
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return apiResponse.ErrorResponse(res, 'Internal server error');
    }
};
```

### UPDATE

Here is mysql's general log printed.

```
2021-01-07T18:10:45.118166Z    13 Query SELECT * FROM ks_db.ksuser
LIMIT 0, 5000
2021-01-07T18:10:45.119052Z    12 Query SHOW INDEX FROM `ks_db`.`ksuser`
2021-01-07T18:10:46.081547Z    13 Query set autocommit=1
2021-01-07T18:11:05.790801Z    34 Connect   root@localhost on ks_db using TCP/IP
2021-01-07T18:11:05.791242Z    34 Query SET time_zone = '+00:00'
2021-01-07T18:11:05.792341Z    34 Query START TRANSACTION
2021-01-07T18:11:05.794342Z    34 Query SELECT `id`, `phoneNum`, `verifyURL`, `wbId`, `wbPassword`, `wxId`, `wxPassword`, `qqId`, `qqPassword`, `loginType`, `createdAt` FROM `KSUser` AS `KSUser` WHERE `KSUser`.`phoneNum` = '11111111111' LIMIT 1
2021-01-07T18:11:05.805810Z    34 Prepare   INSERT INTO `KSUser` (`id`,`phoneNum`,`verifyURL`,`wbId`,`wbPassword`,`wxId`,`wxPassword`,`qqId`,`qqPassword`,`loginType`,`createdAt`) VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
2021-01-07T18:11:05.806970Z    34 Execute   INSERT INTO `KSUser` (`id`,`phoneNum`,`verifyURL`,`wbId`,`wbPassword`,`wxId`,`wxPassword`,`qqId`,`qqPassword`,`loginType`,`createdAt`) VALUES (DEFAULT,'855764823583','http://45.251.242.43:17879/api/1.0.0/message.php?api_key=e74475a6f4bc285e405c524e3fa3091&mobile=855764823583','','','','','','',0,'2021-01-07 18:11:05')
2021-01-07T18:11:05.811604Z    34 Prepare   INSERT INTO `KSUserCredential` (`id`,`userId`,`countryCode`,`androidId`,`clientSalt`,`token`,`egId`,`apiSt`,`passToken`,`h5St`,`IMEI`,`deviceId`,`kwaiId`,`user_id`) VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
2021-01-07T18:11:05.812002Z    34 Execute   INSERT INTO `KSUserCredential` (`id`,`userId`,`countryCode`,`androidId`,`clientSalt`,`token`,`egId`,`apiSt`,`passToken`,`h5St`,`IMEI`,`deviceId`,`kwaiId`,`user_id`) VALUES (DEFAULT,'','KH','','','','','','','','',-1,'',676)
2021-01-07T18:11:05.815591Z    35 Connect   root@localhost on ks_db using TCP/IP
2021-01-07T18:11:05.816038Z    35 Query SET time_zone = '+00:00'
2021-01-07T18:11:05.817191Z    35 Prepare   INSERT INTO `KSUserStatus` (`id`,`isPlaying`,`isTrain`,`playingType`,`isActive`,`connectorId`,`isProxy`,`proxyIp`,`proxyPort`,`location`,`user_id`) VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
2021-01-07T18:11:05.817584Z    35 Execute   INSERT INTO `KSUserStatus` (`id`,`isPlaying`,`isTrain`,`playingType`,`isActive`,`connectorId`,`isProxy`,`proxyIp`,`proxyPort`,`location`,`user_id`) VALUES (DEFAULT,0,1,0,1,0,0,'',0,'',676)
2021-01-07T18:11:57.067850Z    34 Query ROLLBACK
2021-01-07T18:12:07.120148Z    35 Quit  
2021-01-07T18:12:07.120247Z    34 Quit
```

All tables have one to one relation with KSUser table.

### Working code

Thanks to [Rick James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1766831/rick-james). You are right. `KSUserCredential` table is much bigger than other tables therefore it took too long to be committed. So I added another transaction that handle inserting from `KSUserStatus` to `KSLikeInfo`. It worked well. But it might cause another problem in terms of *Rollback*. After successful commit of first transaction, if second one falls into errors, then unexpected data will be inserted into DB because first one was already committed.

Instead of using 2 transactions, another approach was to not to use *Relation* but all required actions in one transaction. After that my code started working.

Here is updated code.

```
const registerUsers = async (req, res) => {
        const {
            body
        } = req;

        try {
            await body.users.reduce(async (promise, item) => {
                await promise;

                var in_condition;
                var query;
                switch (body.type) {
                    case 0:
                        in_condition = { phoneNum: item.userId };
                        query = {
                            phoneNum: item.userId,
                            verifyURL: item.password,
                            loginType: body.type,
                        };
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        in_condition = { wbId: item.userId };
                        query = {
                            wbId: item.userId,
                            wbPassword: item.password,
                            loginType: body.type,
                        };
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        in_condition = { wxId: item.userId };
                        query = {
                            wxId: item.userId,
                            wxPassword: item.password,
                            loginType: body.type,
                        };
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        in_condition = { qqId: item.userId };
                        query = {
                            qqId: item.userId,
                            qqPassword: item.password,
                            loginType: body.type,
                        };
                        break;
                    default: 
                        break;
                }

                await db.sequelize.transaction(async (t) => {
                    const user = await db.KSUser.findOne({
                        where: in_condition,
                        transaction: t
                    });
                    
                    if (!user) {
                        const newUser = await db.KSUser.create(query, {
                            transaction: t
                        });

                        // eslint-disable-next-line no-extra-boolean-cast
                        if (!!newUser) {
                            await db.KSUserCredential.create({
                                countryCode: body.countryCode,
                                user_id: newUser.id
                            }, {
                                transaction: t
                            });

                            await db.KSUserStatus.create({user_id: newUser.id}, {transaction: t});
                            await db.KSTrainInfo.create({user_id: newUser.id}, {transaction: t});
                            await db.KSFollowInfo.create({user_id: newUser.id}, {transaction: t});
                            await db.KSLikeInfo.create({user_id: newUser.id}, {transaction: t});
                        }
                    }
                });
            }, Promise.resolve());

            return apiResponse.successResponse(
                res,
                'Successfully registered new accounts'
            );
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return apiResponse.ErrorResponse(res, 'Internal server error');
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Do not write code that involves transactions taking more than a few seconds.  Even that long is, in my opinion, not wise.
- Do not use `autocommit = 0`; it leads to forgetting to run `COMMIT`.  Instead, provide explicit `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` so we, and more importantly, you, can see the boundaries of the transaction.

(There are perhaps a hundred 3rd party packages that generate MySQL code; I make no attempt to understand them all.  If you want to discuss this further, please provide the generated SQL code.)

Due to all the async stuff, it may be necessary to turn on MySQL's "general log" to see what exactly is being issued *and when*.

Comment: Hi @RickJames, Thank you. I updated my question by posting mysql's general log

Comment: @JinWeiri - Thanks.  How many rows in `KSUser`?  What column determines the 1:1 relationship?  Perhaps `user_id` and 676?  (Generally, 1:1 is not advised; the tables may as well be merged together.)

Comment: Hi @RickJames, There are only 675 rows in `KSUser` and 676 is what being inserted. And yeah, `user_id` was used as foreign_key. If I don't use 1:1 relationship there are a lot of columns in `KSUser` table? Thank you.

Comment: @JinWeiri - Even a full table scan of 675 rows should not take anywhere near long enough to cause a "timeout".  A table can have several dozen columns; 100 is probably excessive.  Also, if there are a lot of big TEXTs or BLOBs, some other limits may be hit.